# Some Insight on the Field of Knowledge Representations and Reasoning

Tags: artificial-intelligence, knowledge, professional-development, knowledge-base

I started following an MS in computer sciences after about two years of work for a software company. I worked primarily in data warehousing and business intelligence related software development during my previous occupation.

There is a high chance for me to select a research in knowledge representations, ontologies and reasoning, as there are no other research available in any other interesting fields, such as pattern recognition and navigation. I developed an interest towards knowledge representation with what I learnt from the courses I am taking currently. But I do not have a deep understanding of it in terms of which areas such a field would have an impact in a real life scenario, and how it will help me when I am hunting for a job in the near future.

Some thought about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The W3C publishes a [list of case studies and use cases](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/sweo/public/UseCases/) which might be of interest. Apart from that, I know several law firms keep ontological descriptions of their cases.